# Why are the Keras based multiple LSTM model's performance much better than the pure Tensorflow based for Time Series Prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a 4 keras based layer lstm wrapped with dropout layer stacked model to do time series prediction. And the Result is not too bad, The code is:

```
regressor = keras.models.Sequential()

# input layer
regressor.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

# second layer
regressor.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

# third layer
regressor.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

# forth layer
regressor.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=50))
regressor.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

# output layer
regressor.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1))

regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=32)
```

The result plot is:

[Expected Result(Sorry for the link cause my reputation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwOrH.jpg)

Than I want to translate the keras based code to pure tensorflow code.

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_time_steps, num_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, predict_time_steps, num_outputs])

cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=num_units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell1, input_keep_prob=0.8)

cell2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=num_units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell2, input_keep_prob=0.8)

cell3 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=num_units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout3 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell3, input_keep_prob=0.8)

cell4 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=num_units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout4 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell4, input_keep_prob=0.8)

lstm_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(
    tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([dropout1, dropout2, dropout3, dropout4]), output_size=num_outputs)

outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_layers, X, dtype=tf.float32)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

But the result is completely wrong. 
[Wrong Result(Sorry for the link cause my reputation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3WZo.jpg)

What's the problem?  Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look into documentations, for example using Keras you have these default settings:

> keras.layers.LSTM(units, activation='tanh',
>   recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', use_bias=True,
>   kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
>   recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', bias_initializer='zeros',
>   unit_forget_bias=True, kernel_regularizer=None,
>   recurrent_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None,
>   activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None,
>   recurrent_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, dropout=0.0,
>   recurrent_dropout=0.0, implementation=1, return_sequences=False,
>   return_state=False, go_backwards=False, stateful=False, unroll=False)

And TensorFlow this:

> **init**(
>       num_units,
>       forget_bias=1.0,
>       state_is_tuple=True,
>       activation=None,
>       reuse=None,
>       name=None,
>       dtype=None,
>       **kwargs )

Can you spot the difference?